# How to manual set minimal value for dynamic buffer in Netty 3.2.6? For example 2048 bytes

Tags: buffer, netty

I need to receive full packet from other IP (navigation device) by TCP/IP.
The device has to send 966 bytes periodically (over one minute), for example.
In my case first received buffer has length 256 bytes (first piece of packet), the second is 710 bytes (last piece of packet), the third is full packet (966 bytes).
How to manual set minimal value for first received buffer length?

This is piece of my code:

```
Executor bossExecutors = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Executor workerExecutors = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
NioServerSocketChannelFactory channelsFactory =
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(bossExecutors, workerExecutors);
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(channelsFactory);
ChannelPipelineFactory pipelineFactory = new NettyServerPipelineFactory(this.HWController);
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(pipelineFactory);
bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory", 
  new FixedReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory(2048)
);
bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(this.port));
```

Comment: Do mean, setting a adaptable receiveBufferSize or create dynamic buffer with optimal size?. If it is the first case, what about using the AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory?. if its about creating a dynamic buffer , DynamicChannelBuffer constructor allows it too.

Comment: I try to use AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory like this:

    bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory", new AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictor(2048,2048,10240));

but it is not solve my problem.
May be you can show me example of how to set fixed length of buffer instead dynamic or about AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what `receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory` you specify, you will see a message is split into multiple `MessageEvent`s.  It's because TCP/IP is not a message-oriented protocol but a stream-oriented one.  Please read [the user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/html/start.html#d0e794) that explains how to write a proper decoder that deals with this common issue.